# Getting error in jmeter websocket single read sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, java-websocket

I am getting error when I try use websocket single read sampler to listen to a server for text messages. I have no idea why this is happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGNi.png)
I expected the jmeter to give me response but it is giving me error.I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot guess the reason and provide your a solution or hint without seeing:

- how to "successful" request should look like, you can get it from [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a [sniffer](https://www.dnsstuff.com/packet-sniffers) tool
- what is response message and code, you need to choose the failing request in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and you will be able to see these along with request/response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and body
- you can also [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the WebSocker Samplers protocol, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

  ```
   <Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
  ```

  once done you should be able to see verbose information regarding what's going on under the hood in jmeter.log file